# Why is my D3.js GeoJSON map not displayed correctly in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, d3.js, geojson

I am using D3.js (v5) to create a map of the districts of NYC. 
In Edge, Chrome and Internet Explorer, the map is displayed correctly, but I am having issues in Firefox. All my svg paths are drawn, but they are shown upside down and way too small. Therefore, it seems like the projection is not working correctly. I think it could have something to do with `fitExtent()`. I have tried using `fitSize()`, but this doesn't solve the issue. I have also tried using a different projection (for example: `d3.geoAlbersUsa()`), but this also doesn't solve the problem.

When I disable my zoom functionality, the problem still persists, so that is not the cause (and therefore not displayed here).

Has anyone experienced this before or know what causes these differences?
Am I in the right direction that this is because of the projection? And what can I do to solve this?

[image: Chrome - the goal]
[image: Firefox - the problem]
A code snippet:

```
try {
    await getData()
} catch(e) {
    console.error('Error while fetching data', e)
}

const svg = d3.select('#d3-map-holder svg')
const zoomGroup = svg.append('g').classed('zoom-group', true)
let city = zoomGroup.append('g').classed('new-york-group', true)
let nycData

async function getData() {
    [nycData] = await Promise.all([ d3.json('https://services5.arcgis.com/GfwWNkhOj9bNBqoJ/arcgis/rest/services/nybb/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=geojson')
    ])

 drawChart(nycData);
}

async function drawChart(nycData) {
  let cityWidth = document.body.clientWidth
  let cityHeight = document.querySelector('#d3-map-holder svg').clientHeight

  let projection = d3.geoEquirectangular()
        .fitExtent([[12, 20], [cityWidth - 6, cityHeight - 10]], nycData)

  let path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

   city.selectAll('path')
    .data(nycData.features)
    .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', d => path(d))
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `cityHeight` in Firefox?

Comment: @rioV8 The value of cityHeight was 0. Using `cityHeight = $('#d3-map-holder svg').height()` works! Is there a reason `.clientHeight` and `.offsetHeight` work differently in Firefox? And is there another solution in Vanilla JavaScript? Thanks!

Comment: I think it all depends on how the height is set, fixed number or by %, and how the render engine layout sets particular properties. I don't know if W3C has described what the DOM should do in these cases.

Comment: Hey @RachelRomée, maybe my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966463/g-element-does-not-adapt-to-svg-on-firefox#answer-52020805) about how dimensions are messed up in Firefox will help.

Comment: And as used in the fiddle in the answer that I link to, try using the second approach i.e. `document.querySelector('#d3-map-holder svg').getBoundingClientRect().height`.

Comment: @Shashank - this works perfectly - thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)